# Bootstrap header reverts to white when small

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, bootstrap-4

I have the following code:

```
<div class="container-fluid" >
  <div class="row" >
    <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: midnightBlue; color:white;padding: 0em 2em 0em 2em">
      <div style="float:left">
```

but when the page is shown on a small device such as a phone the background becomes white so nothing can be read.

Comment: If you expect any sensible answers, you need to post a **complete** `code snippet` (HTML, CSS & JavaScript including CDN links) that allows *replicating your issue exactly*. Otherwise, any answers would be based on guesswork and you want to avoid that. Edit your question and post your **complete** current `code snippet` there at the bottom by clicking the *"JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet"* icon.

Comment: What you have as a snippet there now is very much **incomplete**.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
<div class="container-fluid" >
     <div class="row" >
          <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: midnightBlue; color:white;padding: 0em 2em 0em 2em; overflow: hidden">
              <div style="float:left">
```

Just added overflow:hidden in style. This should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect that your styled `col-md-12` div is collapsing to width 0 at small sizes (though I can't know without knowing the styles of the content). If you use `col-xs-12` the width will be 100% on all device sizes - is there a reason not to do that? I suspect it would solve your problem.

```
<div class="container-fluid" >
  <div class="row" >
    <div class="col-xs-12" style="background-color: midnightBlue; color:white;padding: 0em 2em 0em 2em">
      <div style="float:left">
```

Answer (score 0):

`class="col-md-12"` is meaningless  in your code.Furthermore `md` stand for mid size view which of course can't work in small devices. So just delete that class.

```
<div class="container-fluid" >
  <div class="row" >
    <div style="background-color: midnightBlue; color:white;padding: 0em 2em 0em 2em">
      <div style="float:left">
```